# I'm here to eat and annoy you - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm here to eat,
>   For I like your feet.
>   I'll annoy you now,
>   I'll annoy you later.
>   Try to fight my behinds,
>   and it'll get greater.
>   I'm often abused.
>   All I want to do is eat.
>   But your clapping and slapping,
>   makes a defeat.
>   I have no intention of annoying you.
>   It's just my feast,
>   And I'm only taking the least!

**Who am I?**

Comment: Why couldn't it be *any* blood-sucking insect that is most likely to bite on the feet (which many of them are), eg Tunga penetrans? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunga_penetrants Seems like there is more than one possible valid answer here.

Comment: @AE nice argument, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are:

> Mosquito

I'm here to eat

> They bite you to feed themselves.

For I like your feet

> Most of the time they bite on the leg.

I'll annoy you now,
I'll annoy you later

> First they annoy with the sound they make when flying and then it itches after they bite you.

Try to fight my behinds
and it'll get greater

> When you scratch the bite mark it itches even more.

I'm often abused

> Whenever we see them, we try our best to kill them.

All I want to do is eat

> The blood they get with the bite is their food.

But your clapping and slapping
makes a defeat

> We try to kill them by clapping them between our hands or slapping them against the wall.

I have no intention of annoying you
It's just my feast

> They do not want to make us itch, this is just a mechanism how they can get to our blood.

And I'm only taking the least!

> They take only small amount of blood.

Comment: This answer has already been posted an hour ago. Please only post unique answers

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil But that answer was lacking description for half the lines. However, noted for the next time.

Comment: Strictly speaking, they don't really "eat" our blood, since they only use the iron from our red blood cells for their ovules, so the puzzle is a bit faulty here

Answer (score 18):

> Mosquito

I'm here to eat
For I like your feet

> They are most attracted to feet, really

I'll annoy you now
I'll annoy you later

> Yes...

Try to fight my behinds
and it'll get greater

> Not sure

I'm often abused
All I want to do is eat

> Yummy blood

But your clapping and slapping
makes a defeat

> They get smushed

I have no intention of annoying you
It's just my feast
And I'm only taking the least!

> Yum, blood. But I'm not sentient, so you can't blame me

Comment: Since the other answer is more detailed, I marked it as correct. But you deserve as much upvotes!

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> [Athlete's foot / tinea pedis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlete%27s_foot)?

Because

> It's fungus that feeds, generally, on the dead cells of your feet, unless you scratch so much as to allow it access to the keratin in and under your toenails. It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Nope! Nice try though :P